# Can't use decimals in scanner input

Tags: java

I have this code here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Loan {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter annual interest rate, e.g., 7.35%: ");
  double annualInterestRate = input.nextDouble();

  double monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 1200;

  System.out.print("Enter number of years as an integer, e.g., 5: ");
  int numberOfYears = input.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Enter loan amount, e.g., 120000.95:" );
  double loanAmount = input.nextDouble();

  double monthlyPayment = loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate / (1 - 1 / Math.pow
          (1 + monthlyInterestRate, numberOfYears * 12));

  double totalPayment = monthlyPayment * numberOfYears * 12;

  System.out.println("The monthly payment is $" + 
    (int)(monthlyPayment * 100) / 100.0);
  System.out.println("The total payment is $" + 
    (int)(totalPayment * 100) /100.0);

   }
}
```

The annualInterestRate is a double value but when i try to enter a decimal like 5.4, i get an error. Using whole numbers works perfectly fine.
Anything wrong with the code? Thanks:)

Comment: Please post more information about the error. Is an exception thrown? If so, post the stack trace.

Comment: At a glance, it looks to be because you're trying to convert the monthlyPayment double to an int. When the double value isn't a whole number, Java won't know what to do with it. Can't say for certain without details of the error.

Comment: have you tried using `5,4` as input? Maybe your locale is off.

Comment: @mangotang Enter annual interest rate, e.g., 7.35%: 5.4
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
 at Loan.main(Loan.java:7)

Comment: Consider the Locale ....7.35 is not the same as 7,35 when you have different locale set

Comment: Doesn't seem to error for me when I enter 5.4 as the interest rate.

Comment: I dont really know much about it, but I don't think the problem is that i cast the double to int because it is in the output section. Could it be something wrong with my settings in eclipse?

Comment: No errors for me, my input: 9.9   2   120.98

Comment: But did you tried with `7,35` as _luk2302_ and _ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ_ said. This is generaly the reason why a `nextDouble()` failed. Because depending on your system (and the locale set), the decimal is `,` or `.`. Use `System.out.println(Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName());` to see the Locale you use

Comment: Weird, I tried using a comma instead of a period and it worked! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yea maybe not, but the book i was reading used period. Im from Norway

Comment: Check this [list](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html), you will see that the locale for Norway is like `4.294.967.295,000`. See my answer to change that.

Comment: Ok, good to know thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your locale (Norway) use `,` as decimal delimiter as it is specified in [the list of Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html) looks like :

> 4.294.967.295,000

As the doc sais :

> A scanner's initial locale is the value returned by the Locale.getDefault()

But you can change the `Scanner` locale with `useLocale(Locale)` like this :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(ystem.in);    
sc.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

As said by the doc

> It may be changed via the useLocale(java.util.Locale) method

This will accept a `.` as delimiter.

[The full documentation is here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)